# Removing elements on a List while iterating through it

Tags: java

I needed a way to remove elements on a `List` while iterating through it.

Supposedly something like this *(illegal code)*:

> ```
> List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
> nums.add(1);
> nums.add(2);
> nums.add(3);
> ...
> nums.add(10);
>
> System.out.println("BEFORE REMOVE: " + nums);
>
> for (Integer integer : nums) {
>     if (integer < 3) {
>         //not allowed
>         nums.remove(integer);
>     }
> }
> ```

But we all know that the above code is not allowed.

**So what I'm doing right now** is that I create another `List`, where I'm putting every element that meets a given condition, then iterate through that `List` to get the elements that I need to remove on the first `List`.

```
List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList();
for (Integer integer : nums) {
    if (integer < 3) {
        toRemove.add(integer);
    }
}

for (Integer integer : toRemove) {
    nums.remove(integer);
}

System.out.println("AFTER REMOVE: " + nums);
```

I know it's not really long, but is there a better way to do this?

Is there some API that I can use?

Comment: I think you can use nums.removeAll(toRemove)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Let's look at the alternatives:

## Iterating over a copy, removing from original

This is a simple solution for the underlying problem of your first code: A `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown because you iterate through the list and removing from it at the same time.

Easy solution is to create a copy of the list and iterate through that.

```
for (Integer integer : new ArrayList<>(nums)) {
    if (integer < 3) {
        nums.remove(integer);
    }
}
```

Down-sides of this approach:

- Creates a copy of the original list, which requires memory and an operation which performance depends on the type of the list (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.)
- Additionally, `nums.remove(value)` is a \$O(n)\$ operation. Making this loop overall \$O(n^2)\$

## Java 8 Streams

```
List<Integer> filteredList = nums.stream().filter(i -> i >= 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Down-sides:

- Does not actually modify the existing list, so if references to the list are spread around various variables, you still have some old elements that just shouldn't be in that list.
- Creates various stream-related objects which might not be the most effective option.

On the up-side, this is among the fastest for bigger lists.

**If you're not using Java 8:**

```
List<Object> originalList;
List<Object> newList = new YourFavoriteListType<>();
for (Object obj : originalList) {
    if (shouldKeep(obj)) {
        newList.add(obj);
    }
}
```

## Java 8 method

```
nums.removeIf(i -> i < 3);
```

Java 8 introduced the default method `removeIf` on the `Collection` interface. This allows different implementations to have implementation-specific performance-optimized implementations of this method.

## Iterator.remove()

```
Iterator<Integer> it = nums.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Integer integer = it.next();
    if (integer < 3) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

The only down-side of this approach is that you need to switch your for-each to a `while`. However, this approach is the most efficient one, especially for `LinkedList` where it is \$O(n)\$ (it's \$O(n^2)\$ for `ArrayList` because it has to copy array data on each `remove(index)` call). This is the approach I would recommend in most cases.

Note: Instead of using a while-loop it can also be written as:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer integer = it.next();
    ...
```

## Conclusion

If you want to mutate the existing list, `removeIf` is the solution I would go with. If you like functional programming and prefer a new list instead of mutating the existing one, then go with the `list.stream().filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList())` approach.

## See also

["When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: It's `O(n)` for a `LinkedList`, but `O(n**2)` for an `ArrayList`. There's nothing the iterator could do to avoid the moving of data.

Comment: @maaartinus True, but it does depend a little bit on how `System.arraycopy` is implemented, as it is a `native` call. I tend to think of it as a pure memory-copy call which I more think of as O(1) instead of O(n), but looking at a [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494799/1310566) it seems like it is likely to be O(n).

Comment: It used to be a native call when Java was terribly slow. It's no magic bullet, anymore. Now, it's a JVM intrinsic, which means that the JITc replaces the code by something smart and fast (using XMM registers). But it still remains `O(n)`. I could imagine fooling around with virtual memory mappings, which would be even much faster, but still `O(n)`. Anyway, it would apply to shift amounts being multiples of the page size, so let's forget it.

Comment: @maaartinus To keep O(n) for an `ArrayList` simply loop and collect all elements to be removed in a separate collection, then call `removeAll()` on the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @bowmore Right, but the separate must have `O(1)` access for this. So you need something like a `HashMap` , which in turn has a rather high overhead (not really high, but high when compared to a list). I'd bet that collecting the *wanted* elements a second list is at least 3x faster.

Answer (score 22):

Just had to do something very similar (hence why I'm here), ended up using **Java8**'s `Collection.removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`

With your code it would look like:

```
nums.removeIf((Integer i)->{return i<3;});
```

And if you wanted to collect the removes:

```
List<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<>();
nums.removeIf(
    (Integer i)->{
        boolean remove = i<3;
        if (remove) {
            removed.add(i);
        }
        return remove;
    });
```

Comment: I like this way for Java 8 as it is much more concise while still clear enough. However, internally (looking at the JDK code) it seems to still use an iterator and call iterator.remove(). So performance considerations listed in other posts still hold.

Answer (score 7):

Out of the other presented solutions, all but the one using Java 8 seem to be `O(n**2)`, i.e., too slow when the list(*) gets a bit bigger.

The simplest fast solution is to create an empty list and add all elements not less than three.

If you need to modify the original list, then clean if afterwards and add all elements from the auxiliary list.

---

(*) Unless it's a `LinkedList`, which excels here. But its performance in all other scenarios is so terrible that it should be practically never used.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Simon's answer, you could use a reversed for loop to go through your array to remove items you don't want. It remains an O(n^2) operation because of the `remove` method. So this approach isn't any better, but it's a different way to do it.

```
for(int index = array.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if(array.get(index) < 3){
        array.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bit faster as it moves no elements to be removed later. But agreed, it's still `O(n**2)`.

Comment: `array.get` is a slow operation on a `LinkedList`, it would be better to use `array.listIterator()` which is capable of going backwards.

Comment: Iterating using an old-fashioned for-loop does solve the `ConcurrentModificationException` though. (even if it would be a forward one you could just decrease the index every time an item has been removed)

Comment: Well, the OP has an `Arraylist<>`, so I went with the ArrayList! And I find it clearer to use a reversed loop instead of messing with the index inside the loop

Comment: Because the `ArrayList.get` is an O(1) operation

Comment: Totally agree that it's better to use a reversed loop than to mess with the index!

Comment: Isn't this one the fastest solution presented?

Answer (score 5):

Another perhaps interesting option is using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

```
@Test
public void testCanRemoveFromCopyOnWriteArrayList() {
    List<Integer> nums = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    for (Integer num : nums) {
        if (num < 3) {
            nums.remove(num);
        }
    }
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5), nums);
}
```

The downside is obvious, from the name of the class: it copies the underlying list before every write operation. This class is designed for *observer lists*, which are rarely modified and often traversed. I'm not sure if this applies to your case (if deleting from the list will be frequent or not), but I thought I'd mention this just in case.