# Deleting an item from a Set while iterating

Tags: java, iteration

I know that I'm not suppose to alter a Set as I iterate through it. But, in the `deleteRow(String counter, String reading)` method below, doing just that will make the code much more readable and clean.

Because there is so little going on in each iteration:

1. Is there risk?
2. Would a respectable coder look at that and consider it flawed?

```
public static class DbTable {
    public enum Columns { counter, reading, dfEng }
    public Set<Row> tableData = new HashSet<Row>();

    public void deleteRow(String counter, String reading) {
        Row deleteThis = null;
        for(Row r : tableData) {
            if((r.counter.equals(counter)) && (r.reading.equals(reading))) {
                // tableData.remove(r); <--- I want to do this, and 
                // return; <--- then this to have cleaner code.
                deleteThis = r;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(deleteThis != null) { tableData.remove(deleteThis); }
    }
            public static class Row {
                public final String counter, reading, dfEng;
                public Row(String counter, String reading, String dfEng) {
                    this.counter = counter;
                    this.reading = reading;
                    this.dfEng = dfEng;
                }

                public String toString() {
                    String s = counter + String.valueOf((char) 9) + reading + String.valueOf((char) 9) + dfEng;
                    return s;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What you *possibly* need is an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), and its [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Removing elements on a List while iterating through it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64011/31562) (most of it can be applied on a `Set` too), I think you might find your answer there.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg So, I conclude that the appropriate solution for me is _Interator.remove();_ . But, as I kick-out of the iteration immediately after the Set alteration, I'm still not sure if there really is risk. Even so, I'm using _Interator.remove()_. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no risk because you are returning directly after removing, or breaking directly after setting the `deleteThis` variable.

However, to make each part of your code as safe as possible, I would recommend to use the `Iterator` approach. The idea is that if you would forget to use `break;` or `return;` then you would have problems. If you use `Iterator.remove()`, then you are still safe.

There is another variant as well, based on Java 8 (if you have that available),

```
tableData.stream().filter(r -> r.counter.equals(counter)
        && r.reading.equals(reading))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(r -> tableData.remove(r));
```

This will not have a big impact on performance thanks to the fact that you are using a `Set`.

Now, I am not fully aware of your exact situation but another option *might* be to implement hashCode and equals in your `Row` class, in which case two `Row` objects with the same properties won't be added to the `Set` in the first place, and if you want to remove one and replace with another, you can do so with \$O(1)\$ complexity instead of your current \$O(n)\$. This assumes though that you are actually free to do this. Implementing hashCode and equals can have other unforeseen consequences.

#### Other comments

- `enum` values should be named UPPERCASE according to Java naming conventions.
- It is unclear what a `Row` really represents, and what a `dfEng` is.
- Since Java 7, you can use the "diamond operator" `<>`, you can do `new HashSet<>();`
- Not necessary to store the `String` in a local variable in `toString` (although it can be useful if you want to debug and see what the method will return).